# Dispatcher MVC multi controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, controller

i have the following dispatcher but I want to have more than one controller, to split my code and have something more clean. How can I do that ?

```
<?php
$nameApp = "goater";

$action = "index";
if(key_exists("action", $_REQUEST))
$action =  $_REQUEST['action'];

require_once 'lib/core.php';
require_once $nameApp.'/controller/mainController.php';
session_start();

$context = context::getInstance();
$context->init($nameApp);
$context->title = "Index";

$view=$context->executeAction($action, $_REQUEST);

if($view===false)
{
    echo "Une grave erreur s'est produite, il est probable que l'action ".$action." n'existe pas...";
    die;
}
elseif($view!=context::NONE)
{
    $template_view=$nameApp."/view/".$action.$view.".php";
    include($nameApp."/layout/".$context->getLayout().".php");
}

?>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't answer that question, as you didn't show, how the controller is called. Is `$context` a controller?

Comment: the controller is called with this line : "require_once $nameApp.'/controller/mainController.php';". The $context is a class to handle some function like redirect, success/error of the views etc...

Comment: I would suggest spending more time with one of mainstream frameworks, it can even any of microframeworks, and learning how such components are build. You can learn a lot of good practices in this way and discover problems, about which you would not even think while writing own solution.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Do you have some example of MVC framework easy to understand ?